# How to load images in monogame? C#

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am having trouble to load in an image in monogame, my load code looks like this:

```
Texture image;
```

Located in the `public class Game1: Game`The assignement takes place in `protected override void Loadcontent()`

```
image = Content.Load<Texture>("logo.png");
```

I have put the image in the Content folder, but the compiler still gives an error that it can't find the image. 
The error is: "An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Additional information: The content file was not found."

Comment: Did you use the content pipeline or add the file manually?

Comment: No I didn't not, but a teacher showed me how to do it. I had to use the MGCB to make a file that monogame could read

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify which texture ( 1d, 2d, 3d ) you want to use. This should work:

```
image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("logo.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify the file extension when loading files from the content pipeline. Use this code instead:

```
image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("logo");
```